# How to set Logo and Text On Image In Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have one image one logo and some text. I just want to add a logo and text on an image.
I try it but the logo and text are not set properly on image.

Kindly help on this.

Comment: What did you try?  Please post the relevant code.  You can use a Grid or RelativeLayout to layer the objects on top of each other, or you could use SkiaSharp to actually create a composite image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put it on top of each other like @Jason said in the comment.

2 Images and a Label , first the Grass then the Football and as last the Text.

```
 <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,*" ColumnDefinitions="*,Auto" Padding="30" >

    <Image Source="Gras2.png" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HeightRequest="350" WidthRequest="250" />

    <Image Source="Football.png"   Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HeightRequest="70" />

    <Label Text=" Football "  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"   FontSize="Large" TextColor="White" />
    
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks  for reply @Bas H. The above code working. you made my day.